# Are there ways to make AWS Aurora accessible outside its VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I create an AWS Aurora database MySQL but I can only access it inside its VPC then I created an EC2 instance within the same VPC to open an SSH tunnel and it's accessible from my local machine. But Are there other ways to make it accessible outside its VPC?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.ClassicLink

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear what are your criteria for accessing the Aurora outside of VPC, but generally if you want to access if from the internet, in a sense that its publicly available you would make it, well **publicly available**. For this you can place it in public subnet and set an option in the Aurora settings to have public IP with properly setup security groups.

Off course you do not need to make it open to the entire world, but you can limit access to it to your IP address, or a selected range of IP addresses (e.g. your company's range) through **security groups**.

Recent **AWS blog** explains how to setup public and private endpoints for Aurora:

- [How can I configure private and public Aurora endpoints in the Amazon RDS console?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/)